# G Analytics: They copied my site and distort my analytics data

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

Someone copied my website, and in the source code, obviously is there the Analytics code to track my visits... So the Analytics data is distorted now, because of tracking the other website visits like my own site..

How can I ban this domain? Should I report this problem to google? I really want to penalize this site..

Comment: If you are losing money from this, you should talk to a lawyer that has experience in this kind of situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set up a filter to exclude the domain they're using. (Or just set up an include filter with yours)

[Google Analytics Profile Filters](http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en-us&answer=1033162)

Answer (score 0):

Setup a new profile for your domain. For that profile, you can create a new filter to include only traffic from the IP addresses of your servers.

And yes, you should report the problem to Google, however other than moving you over to a new property ID there is likely very little they can do to address the problem.